# How to extend a class with a constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, constructor

I am having difficulty extending the calCir class to the main class 
I have a constructor that gives

```
class calCir {
    double radius;
    calCir(double r) {
        radius = r;
    }

    double AreaCircle() {
        return Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    }
    double CircumferenceCircle() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }
}
```

I would like to use Main extends calCir but get an error due to the constructor

```
class Main{
public static void main(String args[]) {
```

error: constructor calCir in class calCir cannot be applied to given types;
class Main extends calCir
Im fairly new to Java so im still confused as to how I would use inheritance

Here is the full code if needed
https://repl.it/NA5S/8

Comment: I'd like to know _why_ you want to use inheritance.

Comment: In Java, the convention is to name classes in `UpperCase` and methods in `camelCase`.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to following reason:

when you create a constructor for a class, there won't be any default constructor created for that class. so if you extend that class and if the subclass tries to call the no-arg constructor of its super class then there will be an compile-time error.

As stated here: [Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788963/constructor-in-class-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types)

Answer (score 1):

You have created an explicit constructor for your class. Any explicitly defined constructor will eliminate the default no-args constructor that Java will use implicitly.

Here is the constructor you have created:

```
CalCir(double r) {
    radius = r;}
```

In order to use inheritance as requested, you can do any of the following.

1. Remove the explicit constructor from the parent class.
2. Insert a second construction with no parameters into the parent class:

   ```
   CalCir()
   {
       // Set the radius to default of zero
       this(0);
   }
   ```
3. Override the default constructor in the child class:

   ```
   public class MainSubClass extends CalCir
   {
       public MainSubClass()
       {
          // Set the radius to default of zero
          super(0);
       }

       public static void main(final String args[])
      {
       // Insert program here
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is meaningless to have `Main` extend `CalCir` in this case.

Second, go back to the specific question you asked.

When you have a class (e.g. `Child`) extend from another (e.g. `Parent`), in the ctor of `Child`, it ALWAYS needs to invoke constructor of its parent.  If you are not EXPLICITLY invoking any, compiler will automatically assume you are invoking the no-arg constructor of parent.

e.g.

```
class Child extends Parent {
    Child() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Child extends Parent {
    Child() {
        super();
        // do something
    }
}
```

If in `Parent`, a constructor with arguments is declared, but there is no-arg ctor declared:

```
class Parent {
     Parent(int foo) {...}
}
```

it is illegal for `Child` to invoke the no-arg ctor of `Parent`, because it simply does not exists.

So you need to explicitly tell the compiler which ctor you want to invoke:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    Child() {
        super(123);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any particular reason why you need to extend CalcCir? Your CalCir has a constructor which requires 2 args, if you are to extend it to your main class, then you would have create a constructor in main like:

```
public Main(double radius) {
    // define your params to parent here or have it passed in constructor...
    super(param1, param2); // matching your super class
}
```

Based on the link you provided though, it seems to be more appropriate this way:

Your main class which contains your starting point:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Determining the area/perimeter of a 2D shape.");
                System.out.println("Choose a shape:\n\nRectangle --> (Type a or rectangle)\nCircle    --> (Type b or circle)");
                String shape = b.nextLine();

                if ((shape.equalsIgnoreCase("Rectangle")) || (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))) {
                    System.out.println("Input Length");
                    double length = b.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println("Input width");
                    double width = b.nextDouble();

                    Shape rectangle = new Rectangle(length, width);

                    System.out.println("Area of rectangle is " + rectangle.getArea());
                    System.out.println("The perimeter is " + rectangle.getPerimeter());
                    if (length == width){
                        System.out.println("This is a special type of reactangle, a square!");
                    }
                    break;
                } else if ((shape.equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) || (shape.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))) {
                    System.out.println("Input Radius");
                    double radius = b.nextDouble();

                    Shape circle = new Circle(radius);

                    System.out.println("Area of circle is " + circle.getArea());
                    System.out.println("The circumference is " + circle.getPerimeter());
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not valid choice\n");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Not valid choice\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your Circle and Rectangle classes:

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

    private double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    }

    @Override
    double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }
}

public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    private double length;
    private double width;

    public Rectangle(double length, double width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    @Override
    double getArea() {
        return length * width;
    }

    @Override
    double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (length + width);
    }
}
```

Of which both inherited from shape

```
public abstract class Shape {

    abstract double getArea();

    abstract  double getPerimeter();
}
```

Comment: I needed to use inheritance for a school project but couldn't figure out how to get it to work with a constructor. I know it didn't really make sense using it in this sense but I just needed to show inheritance

Comment: If that's the case then start off with the error you caught. When no constructor is defined in your class, it uses the default no-arg one. Otherwise it uses what you have declared. This in turn is also taken into account if you extend a class from it, if A extends B and B contains a constructor with 1 arg, then you want to create an instance of A, you will need to know how you construct B (in this case pass the necessary arg to your parent via super(arg) in A