# Converting a C++ threading program to a Java threading program

Tags: java

I am trying to convert this simple hello threads program from C++11 to Java. I keep getting an error when I try to do this. This is the original C++11 program:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>

int num_threads = 10;
void hello(int tid) {
   std::cout << "Hello from thread " << tid << std::endl;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // keep track of the thread
    sstd::thread t[num_threads];
    // launch the threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
       t[i] = std::thread(hello, i);
    } 
    std::cout << "Hello from main" << std::endl;
   // have main wait for the hello threads
   for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
      t[i].join();
   }
}
```

And my java code that I have so far looks like:

```java
import java.lang.Thread;

public class ManyHellos implements Runnable {
    private int a;
    public ManyHellos(int count) {
        a = count;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println ("Hello from thread " + a);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int threadNum = 10;
        for (int i=0; i<threadNum; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ManyHellos());
            t.start();
            t.join();
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I keep getting is for my thread line and the error message I get is:

> error: constructor ManyHellos in class ManyHellos cannot be applied to given types

I am not sure which arguments need to go into the line to make it work correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java error: constructor in class cannot be applied to given types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339041/java-error-constructor-in-class-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructor in class cannot be applied to given types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788963/constructor-in-class-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types)

Comment: ...etc. In other words, if you were to search the Stack Overflow site for the error message you're getting, you'd find all the information you need, which is that you've failed to pass any value to the constructor, when a value is required.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor requires an integer parameter, when you use it you do not supply one.

Java offers a default no arg constructor for classes, but only if you don't specify one yourself. Since you created a constructor, the default no arg constructor no longer exists.